# c - Linked Stack Not Linking?

Tags: c, memory-management, stack

My class was assigned a stack implementation in c. For some godforsaken reason, when I push onto the stack and then pop them off one at a time, it only pops one before stopping. Valgrind tells me it's due to a memory issue but i can't seem to pinpoint it.

stack.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stackNode.h"
#include "stack.h"

void push(StackNode** stack, char* data) {
  StackNode* temp = makeStackNode(data, *stack);
  *stack = temp;
}

char* top(StackNode* stack) {
  if(emptyStack(stack) == 0) {
    return stack->data;
  }
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void pop(StackNode** stack) {
  if(emptyStack(*stack) == 0) {
    StackNode* tmp = *stack;
    *stack = (*stack)->next;
    free(tmp->data);
    free(tmp);
  }
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int emptyStack(StackNode* stack) {
   if (stack == NULL) {
     return 1;
   }
  return 0;
}
```

stackNode.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "stackNode.h"

StackNode* makeStackNode(char* data, StackNode* next) {
  StackNode* res = malloc(sizeof(StackNode));
  res->data = malloc(strlen(data) + 1);
  strcpy(res->data, data);
  res->next = next;
  return res;
}
```

main.c

```
#include "interp.h"
#include "stackNode.h"
#include "stack.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  StackNode* stack = NULL;
  push(&stack, "A");
  push(&stack, "B");
  push(&stack, "C");
  while(emptyStack(stack) == 0) {
    char* tk = top(stack);
    printf("%s\n", tk);
    pop(&stack); 
  } 
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

valgrind

```
==17494== HEAP SUMMARY:
==17494==     in use at exit: 36 bytes in 4 blocks
==17494==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 2 frees, 54 bytes allocated
==17494==
==17494== 2 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 4
==17494==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17494==    by 0x400C4D: makeStackNode (stackNode.c:9)
==17494==    by 0x400B57: push (stack.c:6)
==17494==    by 0x4007C4: main (interp.c:10)
==17494==
==17494== 2 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 4
==17494==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17494==    by 0x400C4D: makeStackNode (stackNode.c:9)
==17494==    by 0x400B57: push (stack.c:6)
==17494==    by 0x4007D5: main (interp.c:11)
==17494==
==17494== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 3 of 4
==17494==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17494==    by 0x400C31: makeStackNode (stackNode.c:8)
==17494==    by 0x400B57: push (stack.c:6)
==17494==    by 0x4007C4: main (interp.c:10)
==17494==
==17494== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 4 of 4
==17494==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17494==    by 0x400C31: makeStackNode (stackNode.c:8)
==17494==    by 0x400B57: push (stack.c:6)
==17494==    by 0x4007D5: main (interp.c:11)
==17494==
==17494== LEAK SUMMARY:
==17494==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17494==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17494==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17494==    still reachable: 36 bytes in 4 blocks
==17494==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Comment: Avoid using `exit` like that. Let every function ends naturally and define only **one** exit point of you application.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to return from the function `pop()` and the program exited even if the node is valid.

```
void pop(StackNode** stack) {
  if(emptyStack(*stack) == 0) {
    StackNode* tmp = *stack;
    *stack = (*stack)->next;
    free(tmp->data);
    free(tmp);
    return; /* add this */
  }
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```